# why I cannot use "const string* sp = 0" to initialize in a constructor

Tags: c++, g++

my problem is that `const string* p` gives me an error. What is wrong with this? since I am not change the original value. `const int& n = 0` works fine.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class HasPtr
{
private:
    int num;
    string* sp;
public:
    //constructor
    HasPtr(const int& n = 0, const string* p = 0): num(n), sp(p) {}
    //copy-constructor
    HasPtr(const HasPtr& m): num(m.num), sp(m.sp) {}
    //assignment operator
    HasPtr& operator=(const HasPtr& m)
    {
        num = m.num;
        sp = m.sp;
        return *this;   
    }
    //destructor
    ~HasPtr() {}
};
int main ()
{
    return 0;
}
```

output Error is :

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘const std::string*’ to ‘std::string*’
```

Comment: Do you want to *copy* the string provided to the constructor or to keep a pointer to it?

Comment: I want to initialize the `sp` , as you can see that using `const int& n = 0` to initialize `num` works fine. but why I cannot use `const string* p = 0` to initialize `sp`?

Comment: Ok, but do you want to have a separate copy of the string private to your object or to actually keep a pointer to what was passed to your class? What's the objective of this class?

Comment: Are you sure you want to store a raw pointer to an `std::string`? Who owns this string object?

Comment: whenever I do `HasPtr var`, I want `var` to be initialized to (0,0). also if I do `HasPtr var(12, *ppp)`, I want it to have 12 and *ppp respectively

Comment: @Praetorian `sp` is a string pointer, I am just wondering why this doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because your `sp` member is not `const`.

```
string* sp;
```

But your parameter `p` is a `const`. The result is that you are trying to assign a `const` pointer to a non-const pointer - hence the error.

To fix this, you need to declare `sp` const at as well.

```
const string* sp;
```

Comment: That's because `nun` is not a pointer. The parameter is being copied into `num`. (although it's passed by const reference into the constructor)

Comment: can I use a reference to a const pointer there and make it work?

Comment: No. I don't think that's what you want anyway. Basically, you have two options: 1) Make `sp` const. 2) Don't store a `string` pointer. Store a `string` and let it make a copy of the parameter.

Comment: ^^^ I'd go with option 2) ^^^ Change your constructor parameter to `const string&` and your member to `string s;`

Answer (score 5):

```
private:
    int num;
    string* sp;
```

`sp` is non-const, but `p` is:

```
const string* p = 0
```

The result is that this `sp(p)` is basically this:

```
string* sp = (const string*)0;
```

It's complaining because doing this would remove the string's `const`-ness.

Comment: because `num` doesn't reference `n`, it _copies_ `n`.  It's allowed to _copy_ from a constant.  The correlating `p` parameter would be `string * const`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you got confused by the various meanings of const.

```
 const string*sp;
```

declares a pointer to a constant object, which only allows access to constant methods of class string.

```
 string*const sp;
```

declares a pointer to a string to be a constant member of the class, which you must initialise sp in the constructor and cannot change (except using const_cast<>).

```
 const int&num;
```

in the argument list means that the function promises not to alter the value of the integer referred to by num, but it can of course copy its value (as you did). The corresponding operation for the string pointer would have been

```
 HasPtr(string*const&p) : sp(p) { /* ... */ }
```

and would have been perfectly legal albeit rather unorthodox.